# TableViewCell being called twice

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to apply a line in the middle of my container1 after the the constraints is applied The problem is that the middle line is applied twice in each row. It seems like the layOutSubviews method is being executed twice for each row and i'm quite confused why.?

layOutSubviews method in my custom cell

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    println(self.container1?.frame.height)

    var middleLine1:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(self.container1!.frame.origin.x, self.container1!.frame.origin.y+(self.container1!.frame.height/2), 10, 1))
    middleLine1.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: "#cccac8")
    self.addSubview(middleLine1)



}
```

the println is being executed before the constraints and after on each Cell?

tableView delegate Methdos

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)  -> Int {



    return 1

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BracketCell") as? BracketCell

    cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None





    return cell!





}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `layoutSubviews` implementation is required to be [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). It can be called every time the view's `frame` changes. You should not add a subview in this method. Instead, add subviews in the `init` method and set their frames in `layoutSubviews`.